# Potential for Duplicate Reviews/Gaming in the Help and Improvement Queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement, review-abuse

I've noticed that if I find another user's H&I review (say from their profile), the item is still reviewable for me, and I have the option to edit the post further.

Finding a post that has already been reviewed:
[image: first review]

After reviewing the post myself, I am added to the list of users under "Review completed" with my review count incremented by one:
[image: second review]

This also increments my review count by one, as if I had reviewed this item for the first time straight from the queue.  Is this intentional?

I know that it is possible that a post could be further improved after being reviewed by another user, but this exposes the potential for users to game the review system by reviewing posts that have already been reviewed once to quickly finish their 20 daily reviews without reviewing any new posts that enter the queue.

Comment: This looks like they forgot to implement some sort of non review-able flag after it was reviewed.  I guess they figured since an edit kicks it out of the queue they didn't need it.

Comment: Unless this was intentional, as it is possible for for a post to still need review (or another set of eyes) after being reviewed already.  I find this "trick" to be potentially harmful, since the Steward badge is hard to get in this queue due to the low number of posts that go through it.

Comment: Is this a real problem??  There's an implicit hard assumption that a user can be trusted to make a good faith attempt, especially in that queue.  Demonstrating that the system doesn't trust them, only because he reconsidered his edit, strongly breaks that trust relationship.  There are already systems in place to correct behavior, it doesn't need more than that.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour. Just tested.

Comment: Now I am really interested to see how many can review that. Is there an upper limit?

Comment: What's really confusing is, with <2k rep, I get the "Edit" button when clicking on the link @BhargavRao posted... That's probably a separate bug, however.

Comment: I too can follow that edit link with <2k rep. I'm kind of curious now if I can actually apply an edit in addition to landing on the page

Comment: I participated in the experiment on that review and edited it two hours ago. After seeing this question, I clicked on the 'Edit' button again and made a further edit, but it wasn't listed as a separate review event. The edit was recorded on the question though.

Comment: @WaiHaLee that's the default behavior of the H&I queue, only edits on the reviewable item count.  Even separate edits by the same user on the review item don't count twice.

Comment: @Tuffwer I can see your edit suggestion; should've added a link to this meta discussion in your edit comment. I improved it to force it accepted. Your edit is *not* in the reviewer list.

Comment: @AndrasDeak  Ah sorry, I wasn't even really sure it would work to begin with (and was really an unnecessary edit just to see if it could be done). Is there a way I can add it retroactively?

Comment: @Tuffwer no, and it's moot now, as your edit became accepted when I improved it by removing the boldface from before the code blocks. Just wanted to tell you to be more careful next time, meta-motivated odd behaviour is best left documented:)

Comment: I'm confused, is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Braiam that's what I'm trying to figure out.